# How to create a divs like this pic with css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have been trying to shaping  elements like this . But have not find a way to do this . If anyone knows please tell me how to do this . Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to inspect the website's code in your browser.
E.g. in chrome right click the orange div and then click 'Inspect Element'. In the upcoming window you can see the html code and the assigned stylings.

I think the navigation is made with CSS3 and the transform property. Take a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for reference. 'Scale' and 'Skew' could be of interest for you.

Greetz.